# Simple XQuery on XML feed - help on defining a variable

Tags: xml, variables, xquery

I have never done XQuery before and I need to write a statement using a variable instead of hard-coding in values as this is a live XML feed. (Sorry for such a basic question)

Each event has a name, and a number of places taken, and a number of empty places that are available. Instead of hard-coding in 4 and 11, I want to make these a variable which is that of a specific event.

The event is /event/name = "Rock concert" and I want

```
nb_places = that of "Rock Concert" and nb_empty_places >= that of "Rock Concert"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<bib>
{
  for $n in doc("http://tinyurl.com/")/event
  where $n/nb_places = 4 and $n/nb_empty_places >= 11
  return
    <result>
     { $n/nb_empty_places }
     { $n/nb_places }
     { $n/name }
    </result>
  }
</bib>
```

Thank you :)

Example XML:

```
<event>
<name>Rock Concert</name>
<nb_places>4</nb_places>
<nb_empty_places>11</nb_empty_places>
</event>
<event>
<name>Indie Concert</name>
<nb_places>4</nb_places>
<nb_empty_places>9</nb_empty_places>
</event>
<event>
<name>RnB Concert</name>
<nb_places>2</nb_places>
<nb_empty_places>14</nb_empty_places>
</event>
<event>
<name>Pop Concert</name>
<nb_places>3</nb_places>
<nb_empty_places>32</nb_empty_places>
</event>
<event>
<name>House Concert</name>
<nb_places>4</nb_places>
<nb_empty_places>20</nb_empty_places>
</event>
```

Desired result, events with the same number places as Rock Concert, and the same or more number of empty places:

```
<result>
    <nb_empty_places>32</nb_empty_places>
    <nb_places>4</nb_places>
    <name>Rock Concert</name>
  </result>
  <result>
      <nb_empty_places>20</nb_empty_places>
      <nb_places>4</nb_places>
      <name>House Concert</name>
    </result>
```

Comment: Please post a simplified sample XML and the exact expected output given that sample XML as input. Thanks

Comment: Did you mean, you want to use variable like `declare variable $nb_places := 4;` and then `... where $n/nb_places = $nb_places ...` ?

Comment: @har07 So I'm after: where $nb_places = ($nb_places where $event = "rock concert"

Comment: In that case, my first comment is very relevant to make this question clear. We need sample XML to have a clear idea.

Comment: sure I will post something, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
declare variable $nb_places := root/event[name='Rock Concert']/nb_places;
declare variable $nb_empty_places := root/event[name='Rock Concert']/nb_empty_places;
<bib>
{
  for $n in root/event
  where $n/nb_places = $nb_places and $n/nb_empty_places/number() >= $nb_empty_places
  return
    <result>
     { $n/nb_empty_places }
     { $n/nb_places }
     { $n/name }
    </result>
  }
</bib>
```

Demo : [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/32f297ebe868b51fde8f5f76bbdef6ea)

Comment: Ah because I want to get all events with the same values as the rock concert

Comment: @missdevops now that your question is crystal clear, I have updated the answer accordingly :)